# SharePoint 2013 REST call with CopyTo causes a not well formatted JSON Stream error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, rest

I have written an SharePoint hosted App that performs a local file copy .. first I tested my url with a valid REST call

```
 listurldir = "/appsdev/Marketing Lib;
 itemurl = "/Marketing Lib/betterlivingwithoutprogramming.pdf";

 filename = "betterlivingwithoutprogramming.pdf";

   // Get file to Copy This works with a  GET and no Header
  var urlGetLocalFile = appweburl +
  "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/w eb/folders/GetByUrl('" + listurldir +  
 "')/Files/getbyurl('" + filename + "')?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

ok that works fine by calling a executor.executeAsync() using a GET and no HEADER

....... now the file copy with the above file should be a breeze in my developer site collection... Right.... No Wrong!

```
    localtargetfilepath = "/appsdev/Shared  Documents/EnlightenmentWithoutProgramming.pdf"

    // CopyTo with getbyUrl
    var urlWriteLocalFile = appweburl +
                  "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/folders/GetByUrl('" + 
     listurldir + "')/Files/getbyurl('" + filename + "')/copyTo(strNewUrl='" +   
     localtargetfilepath + "', bOverWrite=true)?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

This time I am using a POST and I have tried various combinations of Headers and Content Types in my Urls but no joy .... anybody smarter than me got this to work?. **One thing I have override part of SharePoint as per this post** http://techmikael.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

```
  executor.executeAsync(
    {

        url: urlWriteLocalFile,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        binaryStringResponseBody: true,
```